# OpenGL GLKView overlay on top of a UI view - iOS/Xcode

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I just put together a GLKViewController custom class that drives a GLKview. Now, I have a UIview on top on which I want to overlay the GLKView.

I did this programmatically in the UIviewController code - i.e. I added code to add the GLKview as a subview on top of the UIview.

However, I noticed that the Framebuffer is not being called at the set 30 frames per second. This in turn does not trigger the drawRect method in my GlkViewController code repeatedly at 30 fps.

What am I missing? How can I overlay a GLKview that refreshes at a set frame per second on top of a static UI view.

Please advise.

Thanks,

Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GLKViewController is deprecated from iOS 5.0 - iOS 12.0. You should move to a newer version.

Comment: I solved my issue but yes, thanks for your reply. I have noted the deprecation. Metal is far better but I first needed to get this out the door on my end.